# Ubuntu server edition UEFI mini pc

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I would like to install ubuntu on a PIPO X8 but i cant seem to the hang of it.

I even lost the default dual boot and i am not sure how but now only android is booting
and I noticed in the bios under advanced->os/bom configutaion:

BOM selection switch [force android/BOM2.1
Pre-OS/bom selection [Android/BOM2.1

So now i cannot boot windows anymore.

But maybe i dont need to know what this is because I actually need ubuntu on this mini pc.

I managed to boot Ubuntu server edition but I dont see all the space on the mini pc when I get to the partitioning part. I would like to have only the ubuntu on this mini pc and no other os.

Anyone done this before?

Any help is welcome and very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer, just to write a solution to this problem:

This link contains mostly the actions to be performed to install ubuntu in pipo x8.

https://plus.google.com/+IanMORRISON/posts/UNWdwRMqy3j

A brief description on what we did to install ubuntu 14.04 in X8:

- The **UEFI is 32 bits** so yo should install 32 bits OS versions
- Download ubuntu 32 bits, create a bootable usb and check  in EFI folder if 32 bits bootable files are stored. If not (by now, this is the case), download the 32 bits bootable files (uefi and grub)
- On startup press F2 to display the UEFI. Disable fast startup . Boot options, select the usb the first to boot.
- Start ubuntu without installing. Then, from ubuntu, install. After installing, **DON'T restart** and execute the file pointed out in the above link.
- Restart and you should be able to start ubuntu.
- Some drivers are not installed (ethernet card, tactile), there is another file in the link to be executed or download proper drivers from internet.
- Now pipo is SUPER-PIPOTE X8, enjoy!

Comment: I actually managed to install 64bit ubuntu with 32bit bootloader. and yea linuxium is the key